# how do i put facts boolean in a slot by then after make a rule who can count it?

Tags: java, jess

i want to count my facts and that facts will have to be boolean. for my intention i only need count TRUE. My problem is if i assert or use deffact to make 4 facts in one slot for example. the working memory doesn´t read all the facts. i tried putting another slot with another data(names in this case)and work good, but i don´t need another slot. i just do it for try to run this code. is there another option? let me show you:

```
(deftemplate testing (slot bole)(slot otro))

(watch all)

(defquery search-by-true

  "Finds true"
(declare (variables ?ln))
(testing (bole ?ln)(otro ?ot)))

 (deffacts data

  (testing (bole TRUE)(otro josue))
  (testing (bole TRUE)(otro pedro))
  (testing (bole FALSE)(otro pablo))
  (testing (bole TRUE)(otro carlos))
)

(reset)

    (bind ?result (run-query* search-by-true TRUE))

(bind ?x 0)

  (while (?result next)

   (bind ?x (+ ?x 1))

   )
       (printout t (* ?x 0.3) crlf)
```

My intentions are learn this by then use objects with java code and jess. how i am going to use JCheckbox and this objects are boolean so that´s why i need to understand this please.
if you have a good recommendation for me i accept it with humility. Thanks.

Comment: Your program works fine, especially when you remove the strange multiplication by 0.3. The result is then 3, as might be expected. So where is your problem?

Comment: yes, like i said that work fine, but if i kit the slot "otro" i can´t count all my facts.. it´s like the program thinks all my facts are the same. i want to use just one slot (bole) in this case.. how do i do it?

Comment: is it possible or no @laune? i put my point up... so what can a do? thanks

Comment: See Ernest's answer. - In future, always post the code you've actually used and describe why that does not work, not some other code!

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your point. i will do it in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you’d like to have working memory contain something like

```
(testing (bole TRUE))
(testing (bole TRUE))
(testing (bole FALSE))
```

... and then run some code that told you there are 2 “bole TRUE” facts. This isn’t possible in Jess: working memory cannot contain duplicate facts. If you try to assert a fact that is identical to an existing one, assert returns FALSE and no changes are made to working memory. You could use your extra slot to contain a serial number or some other piece of unique information.